# what is the expression of angular velocity expressed in the quaternion algebra?

Tags: classical-mechanics

The angular velocity vector :

${\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {\omega }}={\begin{bmatrix}\omega _{x}\\\omega _{y}\\\omega _{z}\end{bmatrix}}}$

the derivative of the quaternion is :

${\displaystyle {\frac {\mathrm {d} \mathbf {q} }{\mathrm {d} t}}={\frac {1}{2}}{\begin{bmatrix}0\\\omega _{x}\\\omega _{y}\\\omega _{z}\end{bmatrix}}\mathbf {q} \,.}$

can i represent angular velocity in the quaternion algebra ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quaternion multiplication is *associative*. So you can simply post-multiply both sides by $\mathbf{q}^{-1}=(q_0,-q_1,-q_2,-q_3)$, the inverse of $\mathbf{q}$ (I'm assuming unit normalized quaternions). This gives
$$
(0,\omega_x,\omega_y,\omega_z) = 2 \dot{\mathbf{q}} \mathbf{q}^{-1}
$$
where $\dot{\mathbf{q}}$ is the time derivative.

NB not everyone calls these quaternions (some prefer "Euler parameters") but it's quite common usage, certainly in the molecular dynamics simulation community.